# DAX Calculted column with running total / cumulative with duplicate dates

Tags: dax, powerbi-desktop

I have this table:

```
ID | ClientID | Date(dd/mm/yyyy)| Amount
-------------------------------------
6  | 1        | 01/01/2021      | 100 
8  | 1        | 01/01/2021      | 150
3  | 1        | 02/01/2021      | 50
1  | 1        | 09/01/2021      | 200
5  | 2        | 03/01/2021      | 100
4  | 2        | 06/01/2021      | 50
7  | 2        | 07/01/2021      | 100
3  | 2        | 07/01/2021      | 50
9  | 2        | 07/01/2021      | 200
```

I need a running total base on the ClientID and the date but if there is a duplicate date I want to Sum the smaller ID.

Expected result:

```
ID | ClientID | Date(dd/mm/yyyy)| Amount |Running Sum
-------------------------------------------------
6  | 1        | 01/01/2021      | 100    | 100 - same date so id 6 before id 8
8  | 1        | 01/01/2021      | 150    | 250 - same date so id 8 after id 6
3  | 1        | 02/01/2021      | 50     | 300 
1  | 1        | 09/01/2021      | 200    | 500 
5  | 2        | 03/01/2021      | 100    | 100
4  | 2        | 06/01/2021      | 50     | 150
7  | 2        | 07/01/2021      | 100    | 300 - same date 7 is after 3
3  | 2        | 07/01/2021      | 50     | 200 - same date 3 before 7
9  | 2        | 07/01/2021      | 200    | 500 - same date 9 is last
```

I tried somthing like that without any luck:

```
RunningTotal = 
var ClientIDValue = TBL[ClientID]
var DateValue  = TBL[Date]

var FilterTbl = FILTER(TBL,TBL[ClientID] = ClientIDValue && TBL[Date] <= DateValue) 

RETURN 

        CALCULATE(
            sum(TBL[Amount])
            ,FilteredTbl
        )
```

Comment: Could you include an additional column in your second table which contains a brief explanation as to how you arrive at your expected result for each line? I'm struggling to see how you arrive at them, and "if there is a duplicate date I want to Sum the smaller ID" is not helping much.

Comment: @JosWoolley - the running total is based on the date BUT when ever there is same date the running total will get the smaller ID